# Test not working

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I want to make a small test but it is not working. I am new to Java and I don't know about boolean and how to use it. How do I debug my code? Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MathTest {
    public static void main(String[] Args){
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Small Test");
        System.out.println("Question one is: What is 9+10?");
        Scanner buckey = new Scanner (System.in);
        double answer;
        answer = buckey.nextDouble();
        if (answer = 19)  {
            System.out.println("CORRECT!!! You passed with an A+!");
        } else  {
            System.out.println("YOU FAILED WITH AN F-!!!!! 0%!!!!);");
        }
    }
}
```

The error is in line 9 and apparently it is `cannot convert from double to boolean`. How do I fix that?

Comment: Glad that your problem got solved, but please don't change your question to mention that. Accepting an answer is all you need to do here and you already done that. So please don't mind that I've reverted your last edit of your question :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `if (answer = 19)` is an assignment and not a comparison. Use:

```
if (answer == 19)
```

instead.

And I suggest to change the variable to int, if you do not want to enter float values:

```
int answer = buckey.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's `if (answer == 19)`. `answer = 19` means you're trying to assign 19 to variable `answer`.

Answer (score 1):

It's `'=='` to compar a value. `'='` is used t oasign a variable a value.